# Convert each pixel from a image to a letter PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, jpeg

I have a file '[map.jpg](https://ibb.co/6vMX5tT)' which is composed of black and white pixels (16x16 img) and I would like to convert in a text file a white pixel to a 0 and a black pixel to a 1. I have this:

```py
from PIL import Image
import os

mapImg = Image.open('map.png')

with open('map.txt', 'a+') as map:
    for y in range(16):
        for x in range(16):
            pix = mapImg.getpixel((x, y))
            if x == 15:
                map.write('\n')
            else:
                if pix == (255, 255, 255):
                    map.write('0')
                else:
                    map.write('1')
```

But I don't know why the result is this in my txt file:

```
000000000
0011000000
0111110000
0100000110
0010011100
0101010
0111100
000010101000
001110000
00011000000
0000100000
0011000
0000010000
00000000
000000000
000000000
```

which is not what the '[map.jpg](https://ibb.co/6vMX5tT)' file looks like.

Edit: Thanks to Random Davis, problem solved! Just needed to change the image format because jpeg compressed the img to much or something, thanks!

Comment: Huh? How come `map.jpg` doesn't appear anywhere in your code?

Comment: Ah yes, mybad, I deleted it on the post

Comment: @MarkSetchell they didn't show where `mapImg` was defined, so surely that's where `map.jpg` is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your image is a `jpg`, then it's lossily compressed, meaning that all the pixels won't necessarily be fully black or white. You need a lossless source that truly has only those two colors, otherwise pixels will be miscategorized.

Comment: PNG is a good lossless format. Of course, your original image has to be a PNG, converting an already lossily-compressed JPG to PNG won't change anything since the damage is already done.

Comment: Ok, Thanks ! You saved my day :)

Comment: @Scaffus. You could just check for > 127 or <= 127 if you know the pixel values are guaranteed to be one or the other

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that jpg files use lossy compression, as the other answer describes, losslessly compressed image files (such as png) can also contain all different RGB colour combinations (e.g. different grey tones). If you are only interested in the difference between black and white, you can e.g. calculate the average RGB value¹ and use a threshold (write a `0` if the average value is ≥ 128, write a `1` otherwise). This will also work for lossily compressed jpg files, as the compression algorithm generally does not change pixels so much that a light pixel will suddenly turn dark.

Your last `if` statement could then be written as follows:

```
pix_avg_rgb = sum(pix) / 3
if pix_avg_rgb >= 128:
    map.write('0')
else:
    map.write('1')
```

¹ The average RGB value does not exactly match the perceived lightness of the pixel due to nonlinearities in RGB colour space versus perceived lightness, but this is out of scope for this question.